# How can I impersonate logged on user and get access to unc folders?

Tags: c#, impersonation, unc

I'm having trouble impersonating logged on user and then access unc files. I have tried using this sample code:

```
using System.Security.Principal;
...
// Obtain the authenticated user's Identity
WindowsIdentity winId = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;
try
{  
    // Start impersonating  
    ctx = winId.Impersonate();  
    // Now impersonating  
    // Access resources using the identity of the authenticated user
}
// Prevent exceptions from propagating
catch{}
finally
{  
    // Revert impersonation  
    if (ctx != null)    
        ctx.Undo();
}
// Back to running under the default ASP.NET process identity
```

If I try to access a file locally where the comment says *Access resources using the identity of the authenticated user* it works exactly as it should. If I however try to do the same thing with a file on a file server somewhere using UNC like \\ServerName\Share\FileName.txt it doesn't matter that the impersonated account has enough rights. The application throws an exception saying that the ASP.NET account does not have enough rights.

I have also tried to use unmanaged code to perform the impersonation and then it works! Local file or UNC, doesn't matter, works like a charm!

The problem is that you have to provide password and since it is the logged on users rights I want to check I can't provide that.

Does anyone know why the application behaves like this? Is it some configuration setting I need to set?

Comment: so to prevent exceptions from propagating you don't even catch and log them!? cooool!

Comment: you're impersonating the ASP.NET Account... not the current user account. what's your authetication mode and you have specficy the impersonate on web.config?

Comment: @Davide: I think it's a sample code... Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334665/steps-to-enable-double-hop-delegation-in-iis7-windows-2008 , and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983443/windowsidentity-winid-windowsidentityhttpcontext-current-user-identity-how-t and here is the source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx#paght000023_impersonatingbyusingwindowsidentity

Answer (score 0):

> Web application runs with specific
>   identity, this identity is based on a
>   user account on the local machine or
>   domain.
>
> The application uses this identity
>   when it accesses resources on disk or
>   services.
>
> If the account does not have rights to
>   the resource, the web application will
>   not be able to use the resource.
>
> Impersonation is where the web
>   application assumes a different
>   identity from the default
>
> Impersonation can be configured to be
>   used for the web application on
>   startup, by adding an  tag
>   to the web.config file. Impersonation
>   can also be implemented dynamically in
>   code, so that it can be turned on and
>   off as needed.

From [ASP.NET Identity and Impersonation](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net_server_doc/developer/adf/aspnet_identity.htm)
[image: Different Impersonation]

So check you web.config and IIS Configuration and ensure that you're impersonating the correct user.